# ignoreEmptyLine parameter not working while reading xslx file in Mulesoft

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to convert .xslx file to CSV in Mulesoft using the "On New or Updated File" node

Input Mime Type is set to application/xlsx and has added one parameter "ignoreEmptyLine" which is set to True.

But it seems in my output CSV file, I am still getting the empty records.

Do I have to set another parameter at the input node?

```
<flow name="excel2csvFlow" doc:id="0539d502-fef3-40c4-8aff-f35ce56304e8" >
        <file:listener doc:name="On New or Updated File" doc:id="2383c725-9ce0-460f-a10e-8a2707174650" config-ref="File_Config" directory="C:\Users\Darshan Vaswani\Desktop\Test\input" recursive="false" outputMimeType="application/xlsx; ignoreemptyline=true" moveToDirectory="C:\Users\Darshan Vaswani\Desktop\Test\archive">
            <scheduling-strategy >
                <fixed-frequency />
            </scheduling-strategy>
            <file:matcher />
        </file:listener>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="9cd75403-0552-412e-a22e-8d7d1215d1d0" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
                                        output application/csv ignoreEmptyLine=true
                                        ---
                                    payload."Daily report international"]]>
                </ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="decd4579-03a3-48ca-bb5a-895885b679a2" message="#[payload]"/>
        <file:write doc:name="Write" doc:id="55ecc67b-fd53-45af-98f5-4a08e663e208" config-ref="File_Config" path="C:\Users\Darshan Vaswani\Desktop\Test\output\test.csv"/>
</flow>
```

Output:
[image: output of my code]

Comment: Without an example input it might be difficult to reproduce the issue and provide a solution.

Comment: Are you sure the lines are totally empty? Not a single space on a cell? A quick hack can be using `filter` in that case with a custom condition.

Comment: Could you please provide a paired down example, an expected output and what you've tried so we can help you?

Comment: apologies for late reply...@aled .sorry I cannot provide input file which I am using  @jorge: it can be possible that one of the cells might contain space but can not guarantee that....I have edited my question with the configuration xml code and screenshot of  my output

Comment: @Dale...csv conversion if working fine....i m trying to get rid of empty records at the end.

Comment: @aled...any suggestion to remove those empty lines

Comment: @Darshan the commas which you are getting are not empty lines, when you are converting xlsx to csv, in your xlsx wherever there is an empty value in the cell mule is iterating over it and adding a ',' after each empty cell iteration.............in order to omit these you will have to invoke a java component and perform xlsx to csv conversion in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ignoreEmptyLine** works as this remove the line from your excel document if completely empty. If any cells in a row have whitespaces then they will not be removed. What you can do is filter them out in your transform step before writing in CSV. This might cause some performance issues if your excel document is too large, but I think if that is the case you can make use of the streaming capability of Mule 4. For filtering logic, you can follow below:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
import someEntry from dw::core::Objects
import isWhitespace from dw::core::Strings

--- 
payload."Daily report international" filter (
        $ someEntry (value, key) -> !(isWhitespace(value))
    )
```

Note that I used someEntry (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-objects-functions-someentry) so it will already return true for the first occurrence of any non-whitespace value and does not need to check other entries in the row. isWhitespace (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-strings-functions-iswhitespace) is used to check if the value contains other characters aside from whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you @oim..your solution helped to achieve my output.